# HTML form submit button not working in mobile phones

Tags: html, forms, button, input, mobile

I have made an HTML form and it is working fine in my Laptop. But, nothing happens on clicking the "Submit" button, when I use that in my mobile phone.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<div class="form">
                <form action="mailto:anubhavmadhav20@gmail.com?subject=MessageFromWebsite" method="post" enctype="text/plain" id="myform">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="yourName"><br>
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="yourEmail"><br>
                    <label>Message:</label><br>
                    <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="yourMessage"></textarea><br>
                    <button type="submit" class="button" method="post" enctype="text/plain"><span>Submit</span></button>

                </form>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the action on the form and not on the button

If the mobile does not have a mailto functionality, you would need a server to send the mail

But the form should look more like this

```html
<div class="form">
  <form action="mailto:...@gmail.com?subject=MessageFromWebsite" method="post" enctype="text/plain" id="myform" target="_blank">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="yourName"><br>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="yourEmail"><br>
    <label>Message:</label><br>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="yourMessage"></textarea><br>
    <button type="submit" class="button"><span>Submit</span></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Try a link instead - works in Chrome for iOS for one:

https://plungjan.name/SO/mailtotest.html

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("mailtolink").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() // remove after testing
    let url = new URL(this.href);
    const name = document.querySelector("[name=yourName]").value.trim();
    const email = document.querySelector("[name=yourEmail]").value.trim();
    const message = document.querySelector("[name=yourMessage]").value.trim();
    url.searchParams.set("from", email);
    url.searchParams.set("subject", "Message from " + (document.title || location.hostname))
    url.searchParams.set("body", name + " said " + message)
    this.href=url;
    console.log(url)
  })
});
```

```css
.button {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form>
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="yourName"><br>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="yourEmail"><br>
    <label>Message:</label><br>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="yourMessage"></textarea><br>
    <a target="_blank" class="button"  href="mailto:...@gmail.com" id="mailtolink"><span>Submit</span></a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But, what shall I do so that it may work on mobile phones too?

Comment: Okay!! Thanks but what kind of server will I need then?

Comment: Okay!! GitHub Pages, it is.

Comment: Well, the javascript code given by you did work. It opened my Gmail App and prompted the Compose Email section. Thankyou so much

Comment: @AnubhavMadhav Remember to remove `e.preventDefault()` after testing. Test the working code at  https://plungjan.name/SO/mailtotest.html

Comment: Now, it's working perfectly everywhere. Thankyou so much, you're Great!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yw. It was entertaining

Answer (score 0):

The mailto-property sends an email from an installed email-program on your device, if it's set default on your os.

Like it says here: 
http://www.tutorialspark.com/html5/HTML5_email_mailto.php

> 2.The mailto link when clicked opens users default email program or software.

Meaning, you need an default email program, or it will not work.

Maybe you don't have an email-program installed on your mobile?

Consider sending the emails from an apache server using php.

Comment: I just have the inbuilt Gmail App, which almost every phone has.